# NuGet Package doesn't have the DLL Present

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

I am trying to compile a solution. I am getting compilation errors such as 
*"Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL".*

*I look at the Hint Path in the project. The project hint path says as follows:-*

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\_packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

I browse to the location. I cannot find the DLL's. What should I do to have the DLL's downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Open the "Package Management Console" window inside Visual Stuido, from there type in

```
Update-Package EntityFramework -reinstall
```

This will reinstall the NuGet package and should re-add whatever dll's that are missing.